# New scheduled report is not running in cognos

Tags: cognos, cognos-8

My newly created report is not running even after i scheduled it. I couldn't even find it in schedule management--> view future activities, even after i schedule it many times in the future time. Please help me where I went wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you view the run history for the report?  (Click on the `More` link, then `Run History`).

Answer (score 0):

There is likely an issue with the JobService.

First, set the logging to full:

- From Cognos Connection > Launch > IBM Cognos Administration
- On the Left Pane > Status > System
- Drill down on the server until you see the services
- JobService > Down Arrow > Set properties
- Settings tab
- Audit logging level for job service > Full

Review the log file:

- Schedule the report
- Remote log on to the server
- Go to INSTALL_PATH\cognos\c10_64\logs (this is my Windows path)
- Open cogserver.log

Find the relevant line. This should give you insight as to why it is failing.